# PHP Upload Premission Denied

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I'm made one upload PHP script that worked 5-6 times... Now when I moved it to another file it isn't working. i'm getting this message

> File is an image - image/png.
>   Warning: move_uploaded_file(Viruss.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/WEB Dictionary/profile.php on line 57
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpySH8hY' to
>   'Viruss.png' in /var/www/html/WEB Dictionary/profile.php on line 57
>   Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.

HTML Code:

```
<form action="profile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" name="ChangeAvatarInput" id="ChangeAvatarInput"><br/>
       <input type="submit" name="ChangeAvatar" value="{$AvatarUpload}">
</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['ChangeAvatar'])) {
 $target_dir = "uploads/";
 $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["ChangeAvatarInput"]["name"]);
 $uploadOk = 1;
 $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $check = getimagesize($_FILES["ChangeAvatarInput"]["tmp_name"]);
 if($check !== false) {
     echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
     $uploadOk = 1;
 } else {
     echo "File is not an image.";
     $uploadOk = 0;
 }
 if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
 }
 if ($_FILES["ChangeAvatarInput"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
 }
 if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
 }
 if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
 } else {
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["ChangeAvatarInput"]["tmp_name"], $Username.".".$imageFileType)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["ChangeAvatarInput"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
 } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
 }
 }
}
```

Premissions of "uploads" directory are Read&Write and I'm using example from W3Schools.

Comment: it's not the upload directory that's the problem. it's the destination directory, which is most likely the SAME directory that your script is in, unless `$Username` contains path information. And examples from w3fools are anything but. their code is crap.

Comment: What was the the previous path? The whitespace in your current path `/var/www/html/WEB Dictionary/profile.php` looks suspicious. Check the permissions of the directory where you move to (uploads) again. Maybe your webserver's user has no permission for this folder?

Comment: @Marc B I'm forgotten to add $target_dir before $Username. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["ChangeAvatarInput"]["tmp_name"], $Username.".".$imageFileType)
```

to

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["ChangeAvatarInput"]["tmp_name"], '/'.$target_dir.$Username.".".$imageFileType)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to chmod or chown the directory you're copying to. so chmod/chown 'upload' so you have permission to write to it

Answer (score 1):

In terminal:

If you are located in your project/upload dir.

```
sudo chmod-R 0755 *
```

This will recursively set permission on all files in folders and subfolders.

If you are not located in your project then:

```
sudo chmod -R 0755 path_to_your_project
```

For file permissions visit this [link](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions).